# How can I know if a viewScope variable has been initialized

Tags: xpages, view-scope

In an application I need to know if a viewScope variable has been initialized. When the viewScope variable is created the value might be null. So viewScope.isEmpty("SomeName") does not tell me that it has been intialized and the answer is null or it has not been initialized yet. None of the viewScope properties seem to answer the question "dose the viewScope exist".

Comment: You can't set null as value of scope variable. If you do so, it is removed (according to my tests with SSJS/binding). It is counter intuitive compared to Java map.

Comment: You can do viewScope.put("SomeName","") and the viewScope variable will be null.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the information whether a viewScope variable does exist or not with

```
if (viewScope.containsKey("SomeName")) ...
```